# Can't find yum plugins for CentOS 8

Tags: linux, yum, centos8

trying to develop my Unix administration skills I've installed CentOS 8.1 to get some practice, but I faced a problem when attempting to install yum plugins - no matches found. All standard repos + epel are enabled. Google gave me no answer. Any suggestions to a newbie please ? :)

PS. My first post here, sorry if bad formatting.

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum search yum-plugin
Last metadata expiration check: 0:44:16 ago on Mon 30 Mar 2020 01:06:06 PM CEST.
No matches found.
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum repolist
Last metadata expiration check: 0:33:11 ago on Mon 30 Mar 2020 01:06:06 PM CEST.
repo id                           repo name                                                                   status
AppStream                         CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                        5,120
BaseOS                            CentOS-8 - Base                                                             2,126
PowerTools                        CentOS-8 - PowerTools                                                       1,525
*epel                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                              5,120
*epel-modular                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                          0
extras                            CentOS-8 - Extras                                                              13
```

Comment: `dnf search dnf-plugin` ... I.e. CentOS 8 : "DNF or Dandified yum is the next generation version of yum." .... No yum-plugins for CentOS 8.

Comment: @KnudLarsen thanks a lot, this explains a lot !